# create another column based on matching of two data frames columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, machine-learning

I have two data frames df1 and df2 with a common column ID. Both the data frames have different number of rows and columns.
I want to compare these two dataframe ID’s. I want to create another column y in df1 and for all the common id’s present in df1 and df2 the value of y should be 0 else 1.
For example df1 is

```
Id col1 col2

1   Abc  def

2   Geh  ghk 

3   Abd  fg

1   Dfg  abc
```

And df2 is

```
Id  col3 col4

1    Dgh gjs 

2    Gsj aie
```

The final dataframe should be

```
Id  col1  col2 y

1   Abc   def  0

2   Geh   ghk  0

3   Abd   fg   1 

1   Dfg   abc  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets create df1 and df2 first:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,1], 'col1':['A','B','C', 'D'], 'col2':['C','D','E', 'F']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2], 'col3':['AA','BB'], 'col4':['CC','DD']})
```

Here, pandas lambda function comes handy:

```
df1['y'] = df1['ID'].map(lambda x:0 if x in df2['ID'].values else 1)

df1
   ID col1 col2  y
0   1    A    C  0
1   2    B    D  0
2   3    C    E  1
3   1    D    F  0
```